# EWS from WebSite using user credentials and windows authentication for intranet

Tags: email, authentication, exchangewebservices, intranet, integrated

I am trying to understand how I should configure a web site (ASP.Net) that need to pass the user credential and get some mail things

I get different kind of errors depending on the app pool configure, 
What is the complete way to do it? I mean code + Configuration ;o)

I don't want to write  the user and password but get them through the windows authentication

Thanks

code:

```
Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
            {
                Url =
                    new Uri(
                    "https://xxx/yyy.asmx"),
                //UseDefaultCredentials = true doesnt help
            };
        var view = new ItemView(1820);

        // Find the first email message in the Inbox that has attachments. This results
        FindItemsResults<Item> results = Service.FindItems(folderName, view); 
        //Here I get the error 401
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx), it covers the basics to get you up and rolling. Note that when you use UseDefaultCredentials, you have to be on a domain joined machine, with the user logged in, and you must be targeting an on-prem server. We tested that scenario out and the following code works in that scenario.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            //Replace the URL below with your own, but using AutoDiscover is recommended instead
            service.Url = new Uri("https://computer.domain.contoso.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                                                               new ItemView(1));
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, then you might want to try using impersonation. See [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4ab42ee6-29be-4349-9b10-38526a4bc912/using-the-ews-managed-api-from-a-web-service?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment), where I think they've got a similar situation . More information about impersonation is on MSDN: [Impersonation and EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: thank you for the answer but is still not clear, my scenario is pretty simple and maybe is a double-hoop issue. The IIS application get the request from an authenticated Windows integrated AD user, so it recognize the user credentials. Still I don't know how to pass them implicitly to EWS... The client is logged in, but the FindItemsResults fails with 401 and similar errors

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that UseDefaultCredentials only works for an on-premises Exchange Server. (I don't recall seeing that mentioned in Microsoft's documentation)